# Android Studio change background color multiple times with 1 button click

Tags: java, android

I am brand new to Android Studio and am trying to figure out how to change the background color of my start up app.

The moment the app loads, I see a button on the screen, and when I click, it goes to the color red.

What I want is when you click the button, it goes from red to green to blue than back to red.

However, I keep getting these errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Error:(72, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected

**Main Activity XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Color"
    android:onClick="onChangeColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Test Activity Java Code:**

```
private int colorIndex = 1;
public void onChangeColor(View view) {
    int color;
    if(colorIndex==0) {
    color = Color.RED;
    colorIndex = 1;
    }else if(colorIndex==1) {
    color = Color.GREEN;
    colorIndex = 2;
    }else {
    //colorIndex = 2
    color = Color.BLUE;
    colorIndex = 0;
    }

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }


public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
View view;

//declare a string variable  in java a class
//private var colour = "green";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    view= this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
}
public void goRed(View v)
{
    //if (colour == "green"){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        //colour = "red";
    //}

 }
}
```

Comment: You should add your code!

Comment: There is my code mind the public class main activity extends appcompatactivity and the                  View view.                     Hope you or somebody can help me out so i can switch between colors.

Comment: `The moment the app loads i see a button on the screen and when i click it goes to the color red` Do you see any buttons?! man, Is that your real code?!!!

Answer (score 0):

To give you a excellent help, it will be necessary to see you code.
Any way if i andersted you right maybe this will help you :

On your xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Color"
    android:onClick="onChangeColor"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

On your activity :

```
private int colorIndex = 1;
public void onChangeColor(View view) {
    int color;
    if(colorIndex==0) {
        color = Color.RED;
        colorIndex = 1;
    }else if(colorIndex==1) {
        color = Color.GREEN;
        colorIndex = 2;
    }else {
        //colorIndex = 2
        color = Color.BLUE;
        colorIndex = 0;
    }

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

On you `onCreate` in the activity

```
   View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I am still having some problems and issues.

Comment: You still haven't shown us your code with your button.

Comment: Thats all my code that i have in my Activity_Main xml file and my TestActivity.java file.

Comment: This is my skype if you would better like to chat and talk to me I am very open to sharing all my information i have and talk about it and learn.  My skype name is Mufferinobuff

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want is, to transition over a series of colours over time, and each colour lasting for some 1-2 seconds. You can use Android's default [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Keep Your xml layout same.

In your Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 LinearLayout layout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }

 public void onChangeColor(View view) {
    // start your timer on button click
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         changeBackground(3-millisUntilFinished/1000);
     }

    }.start();
 }

 private void changeBackground(int colorIndex){
   int color;
   if(colorIndex==1) {
    color = Color.GREEN;
   }else if(colorIndex==2) {
    color = Color.BLUE;
   }else {
    color = Color.RED;
   }
   layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
 }
}
```

Hope this might help. If I misunderstood something please comment.

**Edit:** I typecasted View to LinearLayout

Comment: That is exactly what i want and hopefully after the last color it goes back to the beginning

Comment: I also tried to run it but i got this error Error running TestActivity: com.example.bikam.mycolorapp.TestActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias

Comment: I have done some changes, and if this doesn't fix, can you please post exact Activity's code and the line number you are getting error at.

Comment: Here is my skype name so u can reach me so we can solve this issue.  mufferinobuff